# SPARC Assembly if/else if not working

Tags: if-statement, assembly, sparc

I'm translating a C method with two if statements to assembly. I'm having trouble getting a branch to work. I need two branches to be part of the same comparison, and one branch to be on its own. The two grouped branches work, but the lone third one doesn't; even if I use the same comparison, nothing happens with the third call.

```
ifStatements:
    cmp    %l3, %l0
    ble    useThisA    ! works
    nop

    bg     useThisB    ! works
    nop

    cmp    %l3, %l0
    bg     useThisC    ! doesn't work, even if it's cmp %l3, %l0 again
    nop
```

Why doesn't this work, conceptually?

Answer (score 0):

If `ble` isn't taken, `bg` will be taken, and vice versa.  Branch C will never be reached.

You didn't show your branch targets or anything.  It's likely that one of them can be the fall-through case.  e.g.

```
ble somewhere
 ; code for the g case
...
```

Also, I don't know SPARC specifically, but what are those `nop` instructions for?  Is that a branch-delay slot, that's executed whether or not the branch is taken?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I understand branching better now; the branching is supposed to be used to "skip over" parts of code, not just call methods like in C or Java.